# QGIS value relation dropdown filter by overlay_nearest

Tags: proximity, overlay, dropdownlist, filtering, valuerelation

I have in QGIS 3.28.8 two point layers: source_p and target_p
I want in source_p layer to create a dropdown to "TargetFID" field with Value Relation to target_p layer with only 3 nearest points matches on target_p layer. Value relation should activate when I select a singel point at source_p layer ... current_value selected
I tried to filter expression, but something is wrong?

```
overlay_nearest(layer:='target_p', expression:="fid", limit:=3, max_distance:=15000)
```

[image]

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure from the question what is happening, but it seems to me the problem might be in the fact that you are using this tool without some kind of spatial relationship. Generally, the value relation tool seems to be used for field relationships. I personally would run your two layers first through a spatial join and then use the fields generated for my widget.

Comment: I have the same problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426242/using-overlay-nearest-expression ... when typing the expression i can even see the correct values but they are not visible in the form view ??

Answer (score 0):

I', happy with that solution ... it will create dropdown where are only points with range to 30000 meters.

```
intersects($geometry, buffer(@current_geometry, 30000))
```